# ssh-keyscan and mac: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm sitting on a mac trying to add a host ip to the known hosts file before ssh'ing into the machine. Not very used to a mac so I don't know what's wrong, I get the following:

```
km@Karls-MacBook-Pro ~ $ ssh-keyscan -vv -t rsa x.x.x.x >> /Users/km/.ssh/known_hosts
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ssh-keyscan -vv -t rsa x.x.x.x >> /Users/km/.ssh/known_hosts
              ^^^
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
^^^^^^
```

The "fd 3" message is a debug message. You're getting it because you requested verbose output. It doesn't indicate a problem.